# Problem with Mathematica Relationship Building

Tags: machine-learning, core-language, arithmetic, correlation

When I enter the following to get Mathematica to open my pod door I get

[image]

Could someone try and replicate this? Also, my name is not Dave and I throw my own error...

```
poddoor::notdave = "Feelings hurt.";
```

Question is, how can I use patterns to rebuild my relationship with MMA12.2.1 Activation key 3200-2129-BADHAL?

Comment: This is funny, but is there a question we can actually attempt to answer?

Comment: Did you replicate the result?

Comment: On the cloud, the response can be [replicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEEJX.png), so it doesn't seem like a license related issue.

Comment: Did your pod door open, though?

Comment: `WolframAlpha["Are we there yet?","WolframResult"]`

`WolframAlpha["Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything","WolframResult"]`

`WolframAlpha["Who is the fairest of them all?","WolframResult"]`

Comment: [`I know you and Frank were planning to disconnect me`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dSIKBliboIo)